# How to divide Array Length into arrays with lengths that are multiples of 3

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

So I have a fairly large array that contains xyz coordinates, where array[0] = x0, array[1] = y0, array[2] = z0, array[3] = x1, array[4] = y1... and so on.

I'm running an algorithm on this array that is taking longer than I would like it to, and I want to split the work amongst threads. I have my threads set up, but I am not sure how to divide this array properly so I can distribute this work across 3 threads.

Even though I have an array length that is divisible by 3, this won't work, because splitting into 3 can split an xyz coordinate (for instance, if my array was size 15, dividing it by 3 will give me arrays of size 5, which means I'm splitting an XYZ coordinate.

How can I split this array (it doesn't have to necessarily be equal in size) so that I can distribute the work? (for instance, in the previous example, I would like to have two arrays of size 6 and one of size 3).

Note: The size of the array is variable, but is always divisible by 3.

**EDIT:** Sorry, should have mentioned that I'm working in Java. My algorithm iterates through a collection of coordinates and determines which coordinates lie inside of a particular 3d shape (such as an ellipsoid). It saves these coordinates and I perform other tasks with these coordinates (I'm working on a computer graphics app).

**EDIT2:** I'm going to elaborate on the algorithm a bit more.

Basically, I am working in Android OpenGL-ES-3.0. I have complex 3D-object with somewhere around 230000 vertices and close to a million triangles.

In the app, the user moves either a ellipsoid or box (they choose which one) to a location close to or on the object. After moving it, they click a button, which runs my algorithm.

The purpose of the algorithm is to determine which points from my object lie inside of the ellipsoid or box. These points are subsequently changed to a different color. To add to the complexity, however, is the fact that I have transformation matrices applied to both the points of the object and the points of the ellipsoid/box.

My current algorithm begins by iterating through all the points of the object. For those of you unclear on my iteration, this is my loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices*3;)
{ 
   pointX = vertices[i];
   i++;
   pointY = vertices[i];
   i++;
   pointZ = vertices[i];
   i++;
   //consider transformations, then run algorithm
 }
```

I perform the necessary steps to consider all my transformations, and after that is finished, I have a point from my object and the location of my ellipsoid/box centroid.

Then, depending on the shape, one of the following algorithms is used:

Ellipsoid: I use the centroid of the ellipse and apply the formula 
(x−c)T RT A R(x−c) (sorry I don't know how to format that, I'll explain the formula). x is a column vector describing the xyz point from my object that I am on in my iteration. c is a column vector describing the xyz point of my centroid. T is supposed to mean transpose. R is my rotation matrix. A is a diagonal matrix with entries with entries (1/a^2, 1/b^2, 1/c^2), and I have values for a b and c. If this formula is > 1, then x lies outside of my ellipsoid and is not a valid point. If it is <=1, then I save x.

Box: I simply check if the point falls within a range. If the point of the object lies a certain distance in the X-direction, Y-direction, and Z-direction from the centroid, I save it.

These algorithms are accurate, and work as intended. The issue, is obviously efficiency. I don't seem to have a good understanding of what makes my app strain and what doesn't. I thought multi-threading would work, and I tried some of the techniques described but they didn't have a significant improvement on performance. If anyone has ideas on filtering out my search so I'm not iterating through all these points, it would help.

Comment: What language are you using? And what is your current algo?

Comment: Language should be a *tag*.

Comment: You don't want to divide your array into three sections, you want to organize it into sections that are some multiple of 3. You don't technically need to divide it into separate arrays, you just need to control the access to the array. However, I think you may be optimizing the wrong part of your problem by seeking to solve a performance issue with concurrency.

Comment: I suspect your performance issue might be better solved by choosing a different algorithm/technique for calculating which coordinates are inside the shape. For example, are you doing any preliminary checking against cubes or spheres first to reduce the need for finer checks? Then checking against the convex hull of your shape? Are you doing any sorting/filtering on your data to optimize the search?

Comment: I agree with @LorneLaliberte I think it's doubtful you'd want to use threads on this if it's for a computer graphics app too. You probably need a different approach on your algorithm.

Comment: You could probably use some type of QuadTree or other spatial data structure to limit how many vertices actually need to be iterated when you are checking for collisions between your large mesh and the centroid object. You could also think about splitting your large mesh into smaller meshes, and placing those into a QuadTree. Then you could just get the closest meshes and iterate through their vertices. I'm more of a server-side game programmer, though. Still working on my graphical programming knowledge. I'll defer to someone else's expertise at this point. You might try the gamedev SO site.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest a slightly different way to handle it.  I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but please consider it.

This could be easier to see if you implemented it as coordinate Objects, each with x, y and z values.  Your "array" would now be 1/3 as long.  You might think this would be less efficient--and you might be right--but you'd be surprised at how well java can optimize things.  Often Java optimizes for the cases people use the most and your manually manipulating this array as you suggest is possibly even slower than using objects.  Until you've proven the most readable design too slow you shouldn't optimize it.

Now you have a collection of coordinate objects.  Java has queues that multiple threads can pull from efficiently.  Dump all your objects into a queue and have each of your threads pull one and work on it by processing it and putting it in a "Completed" queue.  Note that this gives you the ability to add or remove threads easily, without effecting  your code except for 1 number.  How would you take the array based solution to 4 or 6 threads?

Good luck

Comment: Confused why this is getting upvotes over my answer hah.

Comment: He said he is performing collision detection between those points and a shape. The additional cost of object creation could end up making your solution slower than dealing with the array of native int coordinates. However, like @brohan322 I think you are focusing on the wrong part of the problem.

Comment: Upvoted your answer--I think it's good and directly answers the question that was asked... it should be accepted over mine.  I just think that sometimes stepping back a level and looking at design can be much more helpful when actually trying to solve a problem..

Comment: I agree with @LorneLaliberte overall. Brohan322 is approaching the wrong part of the problem. I just felt like our answers were essentially the same, Bill

Comment: Thank you Lorne, I missed that in the question--removed confusing question from "answer".  @crush I agree, it's why I didn't add code and didn't call mine a complete answer--you have that covered.  I just wanted to add the suggestion of an object to simplify.  Trying to implement the queue/thread thing using indexes is going to be a nightmare and nearly impossible to maintain--and as I said Java optimizes in a surprising way sometimes.

Comment: @BillK Yeah, Java optimizes the GC for short lived objects, and in future versions of Java, some POJO objects will actually be optimized into stack objects from what I've heard. A simple Coordinate object would be a perfect candidate for all of these things. Graphics programming though usually needs optimal speed and memory usage, which is why things are often done procedurally and as raw as possible. I wish we could get some more details on what the OP is actually trying to do with his algorithm.

Comment: @crush very true--but I still think it could be slower--forcing Java to hold onto a large array and share it between threads has all sorts of caching and wordsize concequences that must be taken into consideration.  If the CPU needs to break one word across two threads your performance is likely to be significantly worse--which is why I suggest ALWAYS implement the maintainable solution and prove it doesn't meet your needs before coding an optimized solution.

Comment: @BillK I never thought about that. New rabbit hole for me to go down - love it! Thanks

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that optimization for Android dalvik/ART is not necessarily the same as for Java in general. On Android object creation is more expensive and it can often be critically important to optimize for memory. While concurrency can speed up some things dramatically, if done naively it can actually end up slower than a single-threaded solution, while also making debugging more difficult.

Comment: @Lorne Very true--you just never know.  That's why you always code readable first, test then if it's not fast enough to meet requirements THEN recode it "Fast" and compare.  I've had a situation (cable set-top boxes) where the number of classes completely completely killed the JVM and we had to re-code everything to use fewer class instances.  Made a complete wreck of the codebase.  I'd never say don't optimize, just don't optimize unless you have proven that you have to.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a demo](http://goo.gl/WgJ0cs) of the work explained below.

**Observations**

- Each coordinate is 3 indexes.
- You have 3 threads.

Let's say you have 17 coordinates, that's 51 indexes. You want to split the 17 coordinates among your 3 threads.

```
var arraySize = 51;
var numberOfThreads = 3;
var numberOfIndexesPerCoordinate = 3;
var numberOfCoordinates = arraySize / numberOfIndexesPerCoordinate; //17 coordinates
```

Now split that 17 coordinates among your threads.

```
var coordinatesPerThread = numberOfCoordinates / numberOfThreads; //5.6667
```

This isn't an even number, so you need to distribute unevenly. We can use Math.floor and modulo to distribute.

```
var floored = Math.floor(coordinatesPerThread); //5 - every thread gets at least 5.
var modulod = numberOfCoordinates % floored; // 2 - there will be 2 left that need to be placed sequentially into your thread pool
```

This should give you all the information you need. Without knowing what language you are using, I don't want to give any real code samples.

---

I see you edited your question to specify Java as your language. I'm not going to do the threading work for you, but I'll give a rough idea.

```java
float[] coordinates = new float[17 * 3]; //17 coordinates with 3 indexes each.
int numberOfThreads = 3;
int numberOfIndexesPerCoordinate = 3;
int numberOfCoordinates = coordinates.length / numberOfIndexesPerCoordinate ; //coordinates * 3 indexes each = 17

//Every thread has this many coordinates
int coordinatesPerThread = Math.floor(numberOfCoordinates / numberOfThreads);
//This is the number of coordinates remaining that couldn't evenly be split.
int remainingCoordinates = numberOfCoordinates % coordinatesPerThread

//To make things easier, I'm just going to track the offset in the original array. It could probably be computed instead, but its just an int.
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    int numberOfIndexes = coordinatesPerThread * numberOfIndexesPerCoordinate;

    //If this index is one of the remainders, then increase by 1 coordinate (3 indexes).
    if (i < remainingCoordinates)
        numberOfIndexes += numberOfIndexesPerCoordinate ;

    float[] dest = new float[numberOfIndexes];
    System.arraycopy(coordinates, offset, dest, 0, numberOfIndexes);
    offset += numberOfIndexes;

    //Put the dest array of indexes into your threads.
}
```

---

Another, potentially better option would be to use a Concurrent Deque that has all of your coordinates, and have each thread pull from it as they need a new coordinate to work with. For this solution, you'd need to create `Coordinate` objects.

Declare a Coordinate object

```
public static class Coordinate {
    protected float x;
    protected float y;
    protected float z;

    public Coordinate(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Declare a task to do your work, and pass it your concurrent deque.

```
public static class CoordinateTask implements Runnable {
    private final Deque<Coordinate> deque;

    public CoordinateTask(Deque<Coordinate> deque) {
        this.deque = deque;
    }

    public void run() {
        Coordinate coordinate;

        while ((coordinate = this.deque.poll()) != null) {
            //Do your processing here.
            System.out.println(String.format("Proccessing coordinate <%f, %f, %f>.",
                coordinate.x,
                coordinate.y,
                coordinate.z));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the main method showing the example in action

```
public static void main(String []args){

    Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[17];

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++)
        coordinates[i] = new Coordinate(i, i + 1, i + 2);

    final Deque<Coordinate> deque = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Coordinate>(Arrays.asList(coordinates));

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new CoordinateTask(deque));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new CoordinateTask(deque));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new CoordinateTask(deque));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

}
```

[See this demo](http://goo.gl/4gaoXG).

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to optimize with concurrency, try to minimize the amount of points you need to test, and minimize the cost of those tests, by using the most efficient collision detection methods at your disposal.

Some general suggestions:

- Consider normalizing everything to a common frame of reference before running through your calculations. For example, instead of applying transformations to each point, transform the selection box/ellipsoid into the shape's coordinate system so you can perform your collision detection without the transformations within each iteration.

  You may also be able to combine some or all of your transformations (rotation, translation, etc.) into a single matrix calculation, but that won't gain you much unless you're performing a lot of transformations, which you should try to avoid.

  Generally speaking it's beneficial to keep the transformation pipeline as streamlined as possible, and keep all coordinate calculations in the same space to avoid transformations as much as possible.
- Try to minimize the number of points you need to perform your slowest calculations on. The most accurate collision test should only be necessary for points that you can't rule out as being inside the shape by faster means, using an approximation of the shape, such as a collection of spheres, or the shape's convex hull. Simplifying the shape allows you to limit the slowest calculations to only those points that lie very close to your shape's actual bounds.

  In my own 2D work in the past I found that even calculating the convex hulls for hundreds of complex animated shapes *in real time* was faster than doing collision detection directly without using their convex hulls, because they enable much faster collision calculations.
- Consider calculating/storing additional information about the shape, such as an inner and outer collision sphere (one sphere inside all points, and one outside all points) which you can use as a fast initial filter. Anything inside the smaller sphere is guaranteed to be inside your shape, anything outside the outer sphere is known to be outside your shape. You might even want to store a simplified version of your shape, (or its convex hull), which you could calculate in advance and use to aid collision detection.
- Similarly, consider using one or more spheres to approximate your ellipsoid in initial calculations, to minimize which points you need to test for collision.
- Instead of calculating actual distances, calculate the squared distances and use those for comparison. However, prefer using faster tests for collision if possible. For example, for convex polygons you can use the Separating Axis Theorem, which projects vertices onto a common axis/plane to permit very quick overlap calculations.